# ¿Cómo puedo al crear un Fragment asignarle un valor a una variable de este?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo una aplicación, en cuya Activity principal el usuario puede navegar por diversas categorías para buscar el producto que desee según la tienda en que se encuentra.

La estructura se basa en un `Viewpager` que muestra las categorías, adentro se crean `Fragments` para cada una. Siempre el primer `Fragment` es de bienvenida (`F.b`), por lo que tiene un formato establecido y todas las demás pestañas tienen un `Fragment` con la información de la categoría (`F.c`) el cual es el mismo modelo y se creará según la cantidad de categorías que tenga el local.

La pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer para que al momento de crear los `F.c` le asigne a este en una constante interna con el valor de la categoría asignada?

Ej: un local tiene 3 categorías: c1, c2 y c3.
Por lo tanto se crearan 4 `Fragments`: `F.b`, `F.C1`, `F.C2` y `F.C3`. La idea es que para el `F.C1` pueda asignarle el valor de "c1", lo mismo con los otros 2 fragments.

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo que buscas es agregar una propiedad a los fragment de numeros y pasarla cuando sean creados de esta manera

Primero creas la clase que hereda de Fragment:

```
class CatergoriasTemplateFrag extends Fragment{
 // aqui es donde colocaras tu variable numerica
 private int categoria;
 //Y la recibes a traves de un constructor;
 CategoriasTemplateFrag(int numeroCategoria){
  categoria=numeroCategoria;
 }
 //Resto de tu codigo
}
```

Luego cuando vas a crear los Fragmentos de cada categoria, solo debes pasarle el valor numero de categoria asi:

```
Fragment nuevaCategoria=new CatergoriasTemplateFrag(/*Aqui va el numero de categoria*/);
```